# Add class using Jquery without prepending '.'

Tags: jquery

Adding class in jquery is pretty straight forward. You just have to do this:

```
$('#id').addClass('class_name')
```

Problem is it puts a `.` before the class name in the div. Any way to avoid that. I want to put the class name without `.`

Comment: It won't put, issue is somewhere else.

Comment: addClass will not add ".". Even if you add multiple css classes. https://jsfiddle.net/nwvho9sp/